# Выкидывание исключений в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, исключения

Бодрого вечера всем.
Есть небольшой вопрос к знатокам javaScript. Очень хотелось бы понять суть отлова исключений, для чего это надо и почему не использовать просто if..else
Какое преимущество даёт блок try..catch...finally, какое не даст никто иной
Пример кода, работающего одинаково, только один основан на IF...ELSE, а второй TRY...CATCH, суть выполнения одна и та же.

```
**///Это на основе IF...ELSE**
function sum2(a,b){
    if(typeof (a&&b) === "number") return a+b;
    else if(typeof a !== "number") return "Первый";
    else return "Второй"
}
console.log(sum2(10,2)); //12
console.log(sum2(10,"2")); //Второй
console.log(sum2("10",2)); //Первый

**///Это на основе TRY...CATCH**
function sum(a,b){
    if (typeof (a&&b) === "number") return a+b;
    else throw new Error("Не число");
}
try{
    console.log(sum(1,"2")); //Не число
} catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Суть не изменилась. Обе функции можно использовать абстрактно. Может кто-нибудь "на пальцах" объяснить основную суть использования TRY...CATCH. Перечитал кучу форумов, и некоторые уверены что дело в стиле программирования и всё. Хотя есть другая когорта программистов, которые считают что отлов исключений даёт некие преимущества, но излагают это таким языком (и преимущественно на СиШарп) что уловить основную идею невозможно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а ты уверен, что конструкция `typeof (a&&b)` делает именно то, что ты хочешь? :)

Comment: хм, ну при "тестировании" вроде да, хотя теперь не уверен. Но если уж на то пошло, то пускай будет typeof a ==="number"&&typeof b==="number". Кстати, а в чём разница? Теперь интересно стало

Comment: В том, что `&&` возвращает _один_ из своих аргументов. Например: `1 && '2'` -> `'2'`. А `'2' && 1` -> `1`

Comment: не совсем понял. Это касается именно первого варианта?

Comment: Из того, что пока надумал. Первое, это семантика. Возвращение подразумевает получение какого-либо результата работы функции и неизвестно, хороший он или плохой. Исключение говорит однозначно об исключительной ситуации, о том, что возникла ошибка и неправильная ситуация, что надо ее обработать. Ну еще из плюсов, вы вылетаете в ближайший `catch` как пробка миную всё, не надо проверять результат функции в `if-else` и думать о выходе из глубокой вложенности.

Comment: Вот Ваше последнее предложение заставило меня глубоко задуматься.

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве случаев, действительно, почти любой `try...catch` можно переписать на `if...else`, НО:

1. `finally` подделать не выйдет без дополнительных колдунств и телодвижений.
2. Система выброса ошибок и их свойства (всплытие, обработка типов (скушал свои ошибки, сформировал красивую табличку с доп. данными, а чужие бросил опять), etc.) не зря существует, её условиями не поймаешь.
3. Чистота кода, не нужно городить N веток условий, просто бросил ошибку из любого места, а обрабатывай в одном.
4. Вставь своё.

Answer (score 0):

Без исключений нужно придумывать, как обрабатывать ошибки:

- возвращать заведомо невалидный результат
  *например, поиск элемента в списке - не нашли, возвращаем -1*
- выделять спец.аргумент в функции обратного вызова для этого дела.

```js
function twice(a, cb) {
  if (typeof a !== 'number') return cb(new Error(`${a} is not a number`));
  return cb(null, 2*a);
}

[1, 2, 3, 'a'].forEach(function(a) {
  twice(a, (err, a2) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err); // check for error
    twice(a2, (err, a4) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err); // check for error
      console.info(a, a2, a4);
    });
  });
});
```

Коллбек-ад в чистом виде.
Мы вынуждены на каждом уровне делать проверки на ошибки, несмотря на то, что продолжать мы уже всё равно не можем.

---

С исключениями обработка ошибок упрощается до:

```js
function twice(a, cb) {
  if (typeof a !== 'number') throw new Error(`${a} is not a number`);
  return cb(2*a);
}

[1, 2, 3, 'a'].forEach(function(a){
try {
  twice(a, a2 =>
    twice(a2, a4 => 
      console.info(a, a2, a4)));
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
});
```